# Conv.user.storage property does not exist on type {} Actions on Google DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been working on an integration for the Google Home for a little while, but for some reason I can not get the user.conv.storage.someProperty = "something";`to work.

The error I get it: **Property 'authtoken' does not exist on type '{}'.**

However... this is exactly as their example which you get by looking at the documentation online or in their own code of the imported package.

This is their code, which I assume, works.

```
// Dialogflow
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.user.storage.someProperty = 'someValue'
})`
```

And this is my full code from one intent:

```
app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", async (conv) => {
  const login = await login();
    if (login) {
     conv.user.storage.authToken = login.authToken;
     conv.ask(`hi ${conv.user.storage.authToken}`);
    } else {
     conv.close(`something went wrong`);
  }
 });
```

Note: The code is extremely simplified to only the things that matter. This is not my real application.

Comment: Don't you have to [get consent before using user storage?](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#save_data_across_conversations)?

Comment: @stuartd - Not necessarily. Most countries might require it for PII or personal information (your name, for example), but not other information (if there is an ID that cannot be tied to you specifically). Consult a lawyer if you are uncertain if this is PII or Personal Information or not.

Comment: @DuncanT - What is the value of `login.authToken`?

Comment: My guess is that login.authToken does not exist as login is undefined.

Comment: @Prisoner this is a hash as a string! Also, I left the confirmation for consent out of this example. I will also build this for the future but since this is a prototype that I'm building I didn't need it now.

Comment: @NickFelker login() returns an object with the needed key value pairings for the other intents. So login.authToken is a string with a hash that I want to store for next intents so I won't have to login every time I'm firing an intent.

Comment: @NickFelker - I'm thinking along the same lines as you, except I think that login is {} since the "if" statement evaluates to true

Comment: @NickFelker oh btw, VSCode underlines the word in caps here: conv.user.storage.AUTHTOKEN

Comment: @Prisoner Yeah, login is {} and it evaluates to true, yet the problem lays in that conv.user.storage.authToken does not exist on {}, VSCode underlines the property "authToken" as something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the issue is that the examples are written for JavaScript rather than TypeScript, and the strict type checking in TS is causing the problem.

As you discovered, referencing it via an index rather than with a property gets you what you need. This is a valid workaround, although a bit hacky.

The underlying issue, however, is that when they export the `DialogflowConversation`, the `TUserStorage` type is defined as an object with no specific properties. From [the source](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/73bc3a8b875135941e551ad0b2388511aca3c146/src/service/dialogflow/conv.ts) (at least as of when I write this):

```
export class DialogflowConversation<
  TConvData = {},
  TUserStorage = {},
  TContexts extends Contexts = Contexts,
> extends Conversation<TUserStorage>
```

when you create your `app` object, you can define your own types here if you have specific properties you want to check. From [issue 188](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/188) (which illustrates it with the `TConvData` type) you could do something like:

```
interface LoginStorage {
  authToken?: string
}

const app = dialogflow<{}, LoginStorage>();
```

It [might be argued](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) that you want a GenericStorage object along these lines, although I'm not experienced enough with TypeScript to know if this is really a good solution:

```
interface GenericStorage {
    [propName: string]: any;
}

const app = dialogflow<GenericStorage, GenericStorage>();
```

I've [opened a bug](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/252) against the library suggesting that something of this sort be done by default.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I thought it had something to do with me using TypeScript so I was a little right. Anyways, thanks for opening the bug against the library!

Comment: Your comments talking about VSCode pointed me in the TypeScript direction. Thank you for that direction!

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer! Like I said in my question, the error was in

`user.conv.storage.someProperty = "something";`

For some reason TypeScript didn't let me do this convention so I went for the old fashioned work around:

`user.conv.storage["someProperty"] = "something";`

And this worked! To get the value I called user.conv.storage["someProperty"] again.

If anyone knows why I got this error and would be happy to explain it, please do! I spend some hours trying to get the storage to work...